# KOPS creates cluster that kube-apiserver fails with unknown flag: --enable-admission-plugins

Tags: kubernetes, kops

I don't understand why I'm getting this error? I'm using kubernetes version v1.13.0. I can't see anything being deprecated?

The `kube-apiserver` image is: `gcr.io/google_containers/kube-apiserver:v1.6.7`

Answer (score 1):

Seems it could be renamed to:

```
--admission-control string                                Ordered list of plug-ins to do admission control of resources into cluster. Comma-delimited list of: AlwaysAdmit, AlwaysDeny, AlwaysPullImages, DefaultStorageClass, DefaultTolerationSeconds, DenyEscalatingExec, DenyExecOnPrivileged, ImagePolicyWebhook, InitialResources, LimitPodHardAntiAffinityTopology, LimitRanger, NamespaceAutoProvision, NamespaceExists, NamespaceLifecycle, OwnerReferencesPermissionEnforcement, PersistentVolumeLabel, PodNodeSelector, PodPreset, PodSecurityPolicy, ResourceQuota, SecurityContextDeny, ServiceAccount. (default "AlwaysAdmit")
```

So the docs seem outdated... https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#how-do-i-turn-on-an-admission-controller

But I still don't know why kops is using this possibly deprecated flag..

Probably because I'm using an older version of the `api-server`... And it's probably not deprecated, it just a flag that was changed in a future version.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your kube-apiserver version.

Version 1.6.7 was not supporting the flag `--enable-admission-plugins=.` The `--admission-control` flag has been deprecated in version 1.10 (pull request: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/58123 )

I'm not sure how you managed to have this version on a cluster with kubernetes version 1.13.0, the image which kubeapi should use is:  `k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver:v1.13.0`